# How to add react app into openfin platform

Tags: reactjs, openfin

I'm finding the way to set up an exists react app(use create-react-app) into openfin platform(https://openfin.co/). Could you help share with me some repo, code sample or anyway to implement react app into openfin

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The OpenFin API is injected in the global space so there's no need to import any libraries, just launch your app on OpenFin.

After using create-react-app you can launch your app with the [openfin-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openfin-cli)

```
npm i -g openfin
openfin --launch --url http://localhost:3000
```

This will create an app.json targeting your app (the localhost version - eventually the URL field should be your production URL).

create-react-app bundles the entire build process into some preconfigured scripts so if you want to automate this launching as part of your local development cycle, you may have to eject the project. If you do that and want to use the launched provided by the CLI as a module, it is also available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openfin-launcher), or using the V2 API you can launch an app as demonstrated [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hadouken-js-adapter#usage)